# Download attacments from e-mails

Tags: excel, outlook, excel-2007, vba

I am trying to automatically download attachments that come with e-mails, using VBA in excel 2007

Incoming mails will be in the same outlook folder (call it "Inventory"). I will define a rule in outlook that will move them there once I get them, so that part is already dealt with.

These incoming mails will all have the same subject(call it "Inventory update"). This is also dealth with.

What I need to do is,

1. Download the attachments in the mails mentioned above, to a certain folder(call it "C:\Guncelleme Dosyalari")
2. I will not rename the attachments before I save them.

There will be no other mails in the folder that update mails will arrive. Therefore swiping through all the mails in the folder without seeking the correct subject line is also doable.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Once you open the message (you can use MAPIFolder.Items collection for that), loop through all attachments in the MailItem.Attachments collection and call Attachment.SaveAsFile

Comment: I don`t really know how to do that. I was kind of hoping someone would show how to do that with the code...